# How to use SBJSON parse with using Content-Type and Method(POST,GET) in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, parsing, methods, content-type, sbjson

Already i have worked on SBJSON parsing, that was working very fine. Now, i am working in SBJSON parsing. The problem is the parsing result is returning null(In NSDictionary). I have tested the url in Firefox POST tool, it returned result with the Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded and Method = POST. How to use Content-Type and Method[POST, GET] in SBJSON file parsing? Really i can not find the result in google search(sorry). Please help me to solve my problem. Please suggest me any sample code or idea. Thanks in advance.

This is my code,

```
SBJSON *jsonParser = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
    NSURL *urls = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SAMPLE URL"]];
    NSString *stringUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",urls];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:stringUrl error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Dictionary : %@", dictionary);
```

The dictionary is returning null. How to use Content-Type and [POST,GET] methods in SBJSON file parsing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting valid JSON back?

Comment: Thank you jbat100. Nothing returned in dictionary. It shows "(null)" in NSLog. But, now i just tried in NSURLConnection. It seems returning some responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually fetching the string data at the URL, just creating a URL and parsing that, which unsurprisingly, cannot be converted to a JSON object. You should asynchronously fetch the string data using something like NSURLConnection, or easier ASIHTTP, then parse the result.

Comment: Ya you are right. Am trying NSURLConnection and NSMutableURLRequest. It seems working good. Thank you for Good suggestion and spot response.